# Error authenticating proxy user name or password is incorrect (SQL Server 2012, SSIS Package)

Tags: sql-server, authentication, ssis, proxy

Any help is appreciated. I have a SSIS package that pulls data from one location and dumps it to a .csv file at another location. The package executes beautifully from within Visual Studio. However, once I schedule the package to run via SQL Server Agent it fails with the following error:

> Error authenticating proxy *DOMAIN\UserName*, system error: The user name or password is incorrect.

I'm running the SSIS execution as a proxy holding the credentials required where the .csv file is dumped. The user name and password are correct. The most interesting part is that I've mirrored these settings from a different server where the scheduled job runs without error.

Do the credentials being used within the proxy somehow have to be tied into the SQL Server?

Edit

After changing "Run as:" from the proxy back to "SQL Server Agent Service Account", the error changes (as I expected it would) to this:

> Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE... Cannot open the datafile *SERVER\Directory\file.csv*

Comment: As a test, using the logon/password associated with your proxy, remotely connect to the server where you are trying to run the job.  Then from there try to establish a connection to the second location where the .csv files are to be created.  If this doesn't work, then it may be due a lack of network/server permissions to that second location.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Since the time I posted this question I changed the Credential I'm using to my personal login and received the same error.  I know for a fact that I have permissions in both locations.  Here's another interesting point; per your recommendation I attempted logging into the server with the login/password associated to the proxy.  The login screen produces an error "To sign in remotely, you need the right to sign in through Remote Desktop Services".  This error occurs even after I added the proxy account information to the Administrators and Remote Desktop Users groups.